# Every complete, countable metric space has a discrete, dense subset.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Given a complete, countable metric space, say $X$, I'd like to show it has a discrete, dense subset. This seems like an application of the Baire Category Theorem, but that doesn't seem to go anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the collection $I$ of all isolated points of $X$.  (By the Baire Category Theorem $I$ is nonempty, but that is somewhat immaterial for the moment.)  Note that $I$ is then a discrete subspace of $X$.  If $I$ were not dense, then $U = X \setminus \overline{I}$ is a nonempty (open) set without isolated points.  From here we can construct [in the usual manner](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/319282/8348) a Cantor set as a subset of $X$, contradicting that $X$ is countable!  (The construction goes as in the linked answer, just ensuring that the $x_\sigma$ are chosen from $U$.)

Comment: Ah, so I was heading in the right direction it seems. Thanks for your help.